# How to find an exact solution to a certain linear second-order non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation below came up in some work I'm doing and I'm at a loss as to how to get a non-numerical solution:

$\ddot x + k_1 \tan( k_1 t) \sec(k_1 t)\dot x+k_2\cos(k_1t) x=k_3\cos(k_1t)$

Comment: A more detailed explanation of how it "came up in some work" might be interesting in itself and motivate why you want "a non-numerical solution".  In other words, please add more context to avoid giving Readers the impression you think of them as a crank to be turned.

Comment: I'd break up the tangent and secant terms in the expressions that involve $\sin$ and $\cos$ to simplify first.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't give an answer - I suspect there's no way to get a non-numerical solution.

Comment: Have you noticed that there is a particular solution which is $x(t)=k_3/k_2=const.$. It suffices now to find the general solution to the same diff. equation with zero RHS and add to this constant...

Comment: @hardmath- I have a graphical plot that was generated by numerical iteration but it might be nice if there was a closed form solution available to check the result. It also would be nice if there was lookup table for these things.

Comment: @Jean Marie- Would you be referring to using the particular solution you gave in Liouville's formula?

Comment: I wasn't especialy thinking to Liouville's formula which can be awkward to use... I was referring to the fact that a linear ODE of this type is the sum of a particular solution + the general solution of the same ODE but with its right hand side equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $k_1,k_2\neq0$ for the key case:

$\ddot x+k_1\tan(k_1t)\sec(k_1t)\dot x+k_2\cos(k_1t)x=k_3\cos(k_1t)$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\dfrac{k_1\sin(k_1t)}{\cos^2(k_1t)}\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\cos(k_1t)(k_2x-k_3)=0$

$\cos^2(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\cos^3(k_1t)(k_2x-k_3)=0$

Let $u=x-\dfrac{k_3}{k_2}$ ,

Then $\cos^2(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}+k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dt}+k_2\cos^3(k_1t)u=0$

Let $r=\cos(k_1t)$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dt}=-k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(-k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}\right)=-k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{du}{dr}\right)-k_1^2\cos(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}=-k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{du}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dt}-k_1^2\cos(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}=-k_1\sin(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}(-k_1\sin(k_1t))-k_1^2\cos(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}=k_1^2\sin^2(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-k_1^2\cos(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}$

$\therefore\cos^2(k_1t)\left(k_1^2\sin^2(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-k_1^2\cos(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}\right)-k_1^2\sin^2(k_1t)\dfrac{du}{dr}+k_2\cos^3(k_1t)u=0$

$k_1^2\sin^2(k_1t)\cos^2(k_1t)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-k_1^2(\cos^3(k_1t)+\sin^2(k_1t))\dfrac{du}{dr}+k_2\cos^3(k_1t)u=0$

$k_1^2r^2(1-r^2)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-k_1^2(r^3-r^2+1)\dfrac{du}{dr}+k_2r^3u=0$

$k_1^2r^2(r^2-1)\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+k_1^2(r^2(r-1)+1)\dfrac{du}{dr}-k_2r^3u=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{1}{r+1}+\dfrac{1}{r^2(r+1)(r-1)}\right)\dfrac{du}{dr}-\dfrac{k_2r}{k_1^2(r+1)(r-1)}u=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2(r+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{r^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dr}-\dfrac{k_2}{2k_1^2}\left(\dfrac{1}{r+1}+\dfrac{1}{r-1}\right)u=0$

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to take a closer look at this.